# Knowing set of sums of pairs, calculate variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I apologize in adavnce if it was answered before.

If I had say, 4 variables: A, B, C, D, that are unrelated and only knew sums of any pair from these, how do I calculate values of variables?

All variables are positive but not necessarily integers.

And how would that change if there were more variables? Is this even possible? Or would I have to know anything more?

Comment: For any of the variables $X, Y, Z$, you have $(X+Y)-(Y+Z)+(Z+X) = 2X$. So as long as you have at least 3 variables, you can calculate each variable that way.

Comment: could you post this as answer? It seems to suit what I need most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the variable you want to calculate, and let $Y$ and $Z$ be two other variables.
You have :
$$X = \dfrac{(X+Y)+(X+Z)-(Y+Z)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $A,B,C,D$ are real numbers.  Suppose $A\leq B\leq C\leq D$.  Then, $A+B\leq A+C\leq A+D \leq B+D \leq C+D$ and $A+C\leq B+C \leq B+D$.  Hence, if we order the pair sums as $S_1\leq S_2\leq S_3 \leq S_4 \leq S_5 \leq S_6$, then we know $A+B=S_1$, $A+C=S_2$, $B+D=S_5$, and $C+D=S_6$.

Note that $T:=S_1+S_6$ must be the same as $S_2+S_5$ and $S_3+S_4$.  We have a system $A+B+C+D=T$, $A+B=S_1$, $A+C=S_2$, and $B+C\in\left\{S_3,S_4\right\}$.  If $B+C=S_j$ with $j\in\{3,4\}$, you get $A=\frac{S_1+S_2-S_j}{2}$, $B=\frac{S_1-S_2+S_j}{2}$, $C=\frac{-S_1+S_2+S_j}{2}$, and $D=T-A-B-C=S_6-\frac{S_1+S_2+S_j}{2}$.  There are two possible solutions (with both $j=3$ and $j=4$) if $S_2+S_4\leq S_6$; otherwise, there is only one solution with only $j=3$.

Comment: well, I can't assume I got variables in any order... As I only know sums of any 2 of these,  and any sums at that.

Comment: You can always assume "without loss of generality" that your variables are ordered as I said.

Comment: whole thing is that I don't need raw numbers, these pairs are results of device test. I can only test devices in pairs and need to know which device has which result (single variable of pair)

And you can assume that variables are only in real positive numbers

Comment: You would still be able to figure out which device produces which number, assuming that $A,B,C,D$ are all known, because you know which two devices sum to which of the $S_i$'s.